# understanding hudu docker compose configuration

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose

We are migrating hudu2 setup to kubernetes. We switched to linuxserver.io nginix container from default swag container since we are using ingress controller to manage the certificates.
We have the following 5 components as part of kubernetes hudu setup.
hudu-nginx
hudu-app
hudu-worker
hudu.postgres
hudu-redis

We were successful to bring up the hudu instance in kubernetes cluster. However, we noticed only hudu-app is being configured in nginx default.conf to forward the traffic but nowhere able to find the role of hudu-worker.

We have following questions:

1. What is the role of hudu-worker which is part of hudu docker compose configuration in the context of hudu setup?
2. How it is been connected and serving while accessing hudu application be it using docker-compose or in k8s?